# Convert line endings

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command-line, dos2unix

I have been using `d2u` to convert line endings. After installing Puppy Linux I noticed that it does not come with `d2u`, but `dos2unix`. Then I noticed that Ubuntu is missing both by default.

What is another way to convert line endings?

Answer (score 125):

Some options:

#### Using `tr`

```sh
tr -d '\15\32' < windows.txt > unix.txt
```

**OR**

```sh
tr -d '\r' < windows.txt > unix.txt
```

#### Using `perl`

```sh
perl -p -e 's/\r$//' < windows.txt > unix.txt
```

#### Using `sed`

```sh
sed 's/^M$//' windows.txt > unix.txt
```

**OR**

```sh
sed 's/\r$//' windows.txt > unix.txt
```

*To obtain `^M`, you have to type `CTRL-V` and then `CTRL-M`.*

Comment: on my mac only this works: `tr -d '\r' < windows.txt > unix.txt`

Comment: I learned on mac you cannot use tr to open and write to the same file.  That results in a blank file, but writing to a different name works great!

Comment: @Loren i think that should be your assumption with any redirection.  The destination file is opened before the reading of the source.  Some commands let you do "in-place" like `sed`'s `-i` but use intermediate/backup files anyway

Comment: These answers are generally correct and you could add `awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1' windows.txt > unix.tx` but be aware that the `tr` is deleting **all** `\r`s from the input, not just those that occur at the end of each line as the perl, sed, and now awk scripts would do.

Comment: Redirecting stdout and stdin in the same line kinda messes with my head so I used:

`cat windows_newlines.txt | tr -d '\r' > unix_newlines.txt`

Comment: tr -d '\15\32' working in Ubuntu18

Answer (score 73):

Doing this with POSIX is tricky:

- [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) does not support `\r` or `\15`. Even if it did, the in place
  option `-i` is not POSIX
- [POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does support `\r` and `\15`, however the `-i inplace` option
  is not POSIX
- *d2u* and *dos2unix* are not [POSIX utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), but *ex* is
- [POSIX ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) does not support `\r`, `\15`, `\n` or `\12`

To remove carriage returns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

To add carriage returns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$";ORS="";getline;gsub("\n","\r&");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

Comment: Those awk scripts are GNU awk only due to multi-character RS (more than 1 char in a RS invokes undefined behavior in POSIX so some POSIX awks will silently drop the `$` and retain just the `^`, others can do whatever else they like), they would produce unexpected results when the `getline` fails, they will only operate on the first line of the input, and they will corrupt the input file in some situations and if they were fixed to operate on all lines would cause an infinite loop in others by writing to the input file as it's being read. Do **not** execute those scripts.

Comment: This work on the **same file**, ie. it replace line endings in-place. While the `tr` solutions require different file as an output.

Comment: sed or tr is not working for me.