# Works on localhost but not on web server....session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php

I am a newbie to PHP and have tried everything and also tried the forum threads to try and fix this but after a week - I feel I am no nearer.

The localhost version works fine - no problem. However, when I upload it, it presents me with the following messsage:

> session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php on line 41

Here is the code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/idigitalconn.php'); ?> 
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }
  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_idigitalconn, $idigitalconn);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT login.username, login.password FROM login";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $idigitalconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "header/KS3Yr7.html";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_idigitalconn, $idigitalconn);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $idigitalconn) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else   {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Probably differences in the `php.ini`. Check error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to check is:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Instead of:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

Also put it on top of your code as @Jay explained.

**EDIT:** In this part you need an **absolute URL** (as explained in documentaton: http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

```
header("Location: " . $file);
```

So change it to (or the way you want the absolute path):

```
header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/" . $file);
```

Comment: Tried this, and the error message has now changed to:Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php on line 41

Comment: Have you change that part in puting on top?

Comment: Hi Charles, I have tried again, and the comments on this page disappeared. However, the page has a username and login facility. When I tried to login in I get these errors:Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php on line 66

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php:6) in /home/idigital123/public_html/index.php on line 74

Comment: I cant understand why there are no errors on my localhost version! Its so frustrating...

Comment: Sorry for late response, I've edited my answer so please try it and comment

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` must go at the top of all of your PHP pages and not tested. Checking to see if a session variable is set before starting the session is "backwards".

Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Answer (score 0):

**Linux** uses `\n` as line endings. However your file is using `\r\n` (windows line endings). When sending data from server to your browser, some data is sended because of bad line endings. You can see it in editor with white characters display: [image]

Change it to unix style and everything should work fine.

Comment: Hi Esse, how do I change it to unix style - can you suggest an editor please?

Comment: For example notepad++ has such option. If you have access to ssh on server, you can do it right there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768776/convert-line-endings or download binary to do it on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-eol-to-windows-eol

Comment: Hi Esse, I have downloaded notepad ++ but still do not know what I am doing (sorry)..Could you please explain further how to do what you have suggested. Many thanks & sorry!

Comment: @user3049418 open file, click edit / EOL conversion / convert to unix format. Then save file and upload into server. Edit it only using notepad++ from now on (regular windows notepad will broke line endings again).

Answer (score 0):

By the way make sure You don't have BOM (Byte Order Mark) attached to source files. It causes unwanted character appearing at the begining of the output.