# Cannot execute a command with eval

Tags: bash, eval, mplayer

I have a text file (test.txt) whose contents are:

```
mplayer -fs video.avi -vf mirror
```

If I execute:

```
eval "$(cat test.txt)"
```

I get:

```
 doesn't exist.or
Error parsing option on the command line: -vf
MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
```

But if I execute:

```
mplayer -fs video.avi -vf mirror
```

the video will be played.

Why does `eval` (or `mplayer`?) fail in this case?

I ran:

```
$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

The text file seems to be created under Windows. I copied its contents and created a new file under Linux. Now it works.

But how to get it working with the original Windows file? Do I have to replace some characters?

Comment: Why do you use `eval`? do you really need to execute the content in the current shell? in that case, _source_ it with `. test.txt` otherwise, execute it with `bash test.txt`.

Comment: It is not clear to me in which scenario `eval` might be better than simply `bash test.txt` or `. test.txt`. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: For how to make it work with the line endings see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768776/convert-line-endings) you have to remove the `\r` carriage returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `tr` to strip off the windows `CRLF` file endings and convert it to `UNIX` line termination strings

```
tr -d '\015' <file_with_DOS_endings >file_UNIX_endings
```

To run your original command in with the above logic invoke an explicit sub-shell with the `-c` flag,

```
bash -c "$(tr -d '\15\32' < "test.txt")"
```

Comment: Yes. I've just noticed that it works, if I execute: eval "$(cat test.txt | tr -d '\15\32')". Change your answer to include this command and I'll accept it. I don't want to create an additional file during the process.

Comment: @ka3ak: I have removed the useless use of cat and explicit use of eval.

Comment: You are too quick :) When I saw that your answer was correct (and worked!) I accepted it, but now it is again incorrect.

Comment: Try to execute your second command. bash needs -c option in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Shells don't like files with Windows/DOS line endings. They treat the carriage return ('\r') as part of the last word.

Worse, when a carriage return is output as part of an error message, it places the cursor at the beginning of the line, causing previous message text to be overwritten. This explains the garbled message.

To run a shell script stored in a file, you simply make it executable (`chmod +x test.txt`), then `./test.txt`. No need for `eval`.

You can convert DOS files to Unix files with

```
dos2unix test.txt
```

to remove the carriage returns.