# Faced a bug in android terminal

Tags: android, linux, shell

I know that we can use the following syntax to create a for loop in linux or android shell script :

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
echo $i
done
```

It is working as expected when written directly in terminal :
[image]

But when the code is saved in a .sh file and called in terminal using the 'sh' command, it shows - "syntax error 'do".

Code in a .sh file :
[image]

File called in terminal :
[image]

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening here ? I am using Terminal Emulator in android.
When I am working with other commands in the .sh file, there is no problem with newline encoding.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Have you tried this in android Terminal Emulator or in linux command line? And if you had tried it in android, which android version are you using ?

Comment: I tried both of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16768776/608639), [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/608639), [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/608639), etc.

Comment: Probably your editor is messing with line ending.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh yes, that's right. When I added another new line before the 'do' command, it worked.

Previously I wrote this :

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    echo $i
done
```

Afterwards, I wrote this :

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5

do
    echo $i
done
```

Note that there are two new lines before 'do'.