# linux awk, problem when printing variable

Tags: awk, carriage-return

I am having a problem printing something using the awk command on Linux. I have a file and i use the following line:

```
x="something";awk -v x="$x" '{print $0,x}' myfile.txt
```

I want to print the whole file ($0) and then at the end of every line the x variable. However this x variable for some reason goes at the beginning of the file and not at the end. This is a sample of my file and the output.

[image]

I don't know what is the problem but it is really getting on my nerves!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Your input file has dos line endings. Remove them

Comment: Please check this link also once for removing control M characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768776/convert-line-endings/21219668